# Expanded user card shows links not included in the summary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-card, profile-page

My summary is set up as:

```
<!-- summary: {summary} this is my summary {end-summary} -->
```

So it should only display

```
{summary} this is my summary {end-summary}
```

Right? But if you hover over my profile it shows the Google+ link as well.

Is this a bug or by-design?

Comment: @GraceNote So how do I get rid of them, short of not having links on my profile?

Comment: Aside from not having links... you don't. Alternatively, you can just opt out of the user card as a whole, using the method detailed in the privileges page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, this is the intended method.

To quote the [privileges page on the matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user), the following is what is shown on the user card:

> - A larger resolution of your **avatar**
> - Your **display name** linked to your profile
> - Your **reputation and badges**
> - Your **Location**, if you have entered one on your profile
> - A **link to your Website**, if you have entered one on your profile
> - Your **About Me** section. Up to the first 298 characters will be displayed as the meat of your expanded usercard. HTML links and linebreaks/paragraphs will be rendered, but not formatting such as bold.
> - Any **additional HTML links** will be displayed and linked at the bottom of the expanded usercard. This does not repeat any links that are already shown in the previous part.

It is *only* the second-to-last bullet that is replaced by using `<!-- summary: text -->`. The last point is not affected by it, so any HTML links will be shown at the bottom. Note that because you can't include any HTML links in a summary block (on account of being inside an HTML comment, it breaks), this means that all HTML links in your About Me section will be rendered in this fashion.

Answer (score 5):

I "fixed" this using a workaround, that is, three empty links. Now I can have real links on my profile without having them show in the hover card. Yay!

```
[​](http://example.com) [​](http://example.org) [​](http://example.net)
```